# Getting objects in a situation where their name matters

Tags: r, evaluation

I have a list of functions that I'd like to make documentation for.  My question is not about how to do this, but it provides a convenient example of something I'm curious about.

`prompt` takes a function and a character string as arguments, and writes a help file on that function to the file represented by the character string path.  In looping over the files, using `prompt(f,filename=...)` doesn't work since f is of type character.  I tried `get(f)`, which pulls the function out just fine, but doesn't give prompt enough information to work with (see below).  So how do I force a character element to return the whole object not just the function that it names?

```
files <- c("current.market","current.portfolio.bond","fund","genAccount","genHistory.market","history.market","maRketSim.version","summary.vasicek.discrete","vasicek.discrete")
for(f in files) {
  prompt( get(f), filename=paste("c:/myproject/man/",f,".Rd",sep="") )
}
Error in prompt.default(get(f), filename = paste("F:/Documents/R-projects/maRketSim/man/",  : 
  cannot determine a usable name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?prompt` tells us that

```
Arguments:

  object: an R object, typically a function for the default method.
          Can be ‘missing’ when ‘name’ is specified.
```

So I think `prompt()` already does what you want:

```
> prompt(name = "print", filename = "print.Rd")
Created file named 'print.Rd'.
Edit the file and move it to the appropriate directory.
```

Which does produce the relevant Rd file:

```
> writeLines(readLines("~/print.Rd"))
\name{print}
\alias{print}
%- Also NEED an '\alias' for EACH other topic documented here.
\title{
%%  ~~function to do ... ~~
}
\description{
%%  ~~ A concise (1-5 lines) description of what the function does. ~~
}
\usage{
print(x, ...)
}
%- maybe also 'usage' for other objects documented here.
\arguments{
  \item{x}{
%%     ~~Describe \code{x} here~~
....
```

I should add, that `get("foo")` **does** return the actual function, it is just the way that `prompt()` is coded that it can't work with an anonymous function as returned by `get()`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin.  I just realized a second ago that prompt takes the ,name argument.  But I was hoping for something a little more generic: how to fetch an object with its name information intact.  I'm not even sure where name information about functions gets stored.  Looking through `getS3method("prompt","default")` , it looks like `substitute` is used to return the parse tree, and then that is checked to see if it is a name with `is.name`.  But I suspect that `g <- get(f); name(g) <- f` is not only non-working but conceptually wrong.

Comment: A `name` is just the way to refer to R objects by their name rather than the contents of the object with that name. How to proceed really depends on what you want to do. You could wrap `prompt()` and do various manipulations of `f` to get what you want. But it isn't clear to me what you want to do generically.

Comment: This question may be relevant: [Getting the object name for S3 print method failing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4959463/210673)

Comment: Ok maybe I'll try to find another example of where generically it would be helpful.  Basically I'm trying to learn more about programming-on-the-language so every time I run across a problem where `get` `eval` `assign` `bquote` etc. would be helpful I try to think more about them even if they're not the easiest solution.

Comment: @Aaron Your and Joris' Answers in the linked Q hit the nail on the head nicely.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks.  I'll take a look and see if I can't wrap my brain around this.